# Duplex Link while typed in reverse order

Tags: hyperlink

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1.0Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n1 $n0 1.0Mb 10ms DropTail

is there is any difference between both the line??

Comment: Surely it is: 1-st line has "$n0 $n1" substring, and 2nd one has a "$n1 $n0". Those lines are not equal

Comment: @Banzay yeah i agree but as its duplex-link......so why both the line are different ...end result will be one link will be from $n0 to $n1 and other from $n1 fo $n0.....